# Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, linearity

[image]

Apparently you could use linearity here, but that doesn't make the question any less intricate.

Comment: It looks like a good application for the extra-element theorem or EET. Did you consider using it?

Comment: at every point of time 20V divides by 2 . there will be 2.5V across 6K. so, across 4K is 2.5*4/6  which is 5/3V

Comment: Actually no need for the EET, just build a Thévenin generator combining the 20-V source with the 8k/4k divider and a \$R_{th}\$ of 4k||8k then redraw the sketch and you have cascaded divide-by-2 resistive networks as pointed out by user19579.

Comment: @Bak1139 Please be more specific in your question titles in future so that others can see the topic and gist and so you can find it again later, it makes the site more useful. Try and summarise the question in the title rather than filling it with a rhetorical question, risking a literal but useless answer of "Yes, someone has an idea".

Comment: Yes we have idea how to solve it. If this is homework, where are you stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: This is a contrived question designed to "drop out" by inspection once you see the pattern. | Draw the diagonal 12k as a vertical and move  the resistors to the right of it right. | Now starting at left Note that. 2k+4K = 6K - which is in parallel with a 6k making 3k. This 3k is in series with another 3k and so .... | It works steadily upwards r to l. NOW read what the other comments say

Answer (score 2):

I've redrawn it to make it easier to solve. now there is just a bunch of resistors in a clear series or parrellel circuit,

To solve it linearly, you can begin by working out what the resistance of 8K and all that is in parrellel is, once you know that, you know the voltage at the first node and can work down the tree until your left with your Vo

E.g. 2K + 4K on the right = 6K, that 6K in parrellel with 6K = 3K, that 3K in series with 3K = 6K, 3K in parrellel with 12K and so on, you then know the voltage of that node, and can then divide the next node by there relative resistances until you finally reach your Vo

[image]